# Use cell value as string VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel

Cell A2 contains value "25-86".

I need cell B2 to have value "AJ 2586%"

This code reveals Syntax error:

```
Range("B2").Value = "AJ & Left(Range("A2"), 2) & Right(Range("A2"), 2) & %"
```

If I write it like that

```
Range("B2").Value = "AJ & Left(A2, 2) & Right(A2, 2) & %"
```

The functions `Left` and `Right` treat "A2" as string.

How could I extract a part of text from the cell and enter it in another cell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that everything between the " " defines a string. 
You can type your code like this:

```
Range("B2").Value = "AJ " & Left(Range("A2"), 2) & Right(Range("A2"), 2) & "%"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following formula will return the value as a real percentage that you can use in calculations.
It just removes the `-` from the figure.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")/100
```

Initially it will display the value as `25.86`.

When you apply the **custom number format** of:

```
\AJ 0%
```

It will then display as `AJ 2586%`.

If that formula is in A1 then `=A1/2` will return `AJ 1293%`.

**Edit:**
Just realised you want it in VBA:

```
Range("B2") = Replace(Range("A2"), "-", "") / 100
Range("B2").NumberFormat = "\AJ 0%"
```

Or, if you just want it as text:

```
Range("B2") = "AJ " & Replace(Range("A2"), "-", "") & "%"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("B2").Value = "AJ " + Left(Range("A2"), 2) + Right(Range("A2"), 2) + "%"
```

> Indent code 4 spaces in order for it to be in the correct format

Comment: If you check my code in VBA it works as expected (as + can concatenate without the need of an ampersand). Either way works.

Comment: `Type Mismatch`

Comment: @cmbarnett87 if either of the items being concatenated are numbers then vba will try to add the number to the text string and you will get Type Mismatch.  If both are strings then yes it works, but `&` works will both numbers and strings.  So to avoid the confusion and errors it is generally accepted that one should use `&` instead of `+` where concatenating.

Comment: I think I might have missed that his example had double quotes (which I'm assuming he put in the cell as well?). When I tested it in Excel I didn't encounter any issues with the + or & - again, that was without double quotes.